# JSP forEach loop

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a JSP that I am displaying when validation errors occur in my application. In the Servlet, I set the `ArrayList<String>` of errors in the request, and am trying to print them in the JSP, with the following code. I know there is 1 error in the `ArrayList` because I am printing it out to the server console, but the only thing being printed is the "-". Am I using the `forEach` loop correctly?

```
<c:forEach var="error" items="${errors}">
    <h1>-${error}</h1>
    <br>
</c:forEach>
```

Here is part of the code from doPost in the Servlet:

```
        ArrayList<String> errors = dataValidator.getErrors();
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        String cost = dataValidator.getCost();
        request.setAttribute("cost", cost);
        RequestDispatcher resultsDispatcher = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp");
        try {
            resultsDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException se) {
            System.out.println("Servlet Exception: " + se.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception: " + ioe.toString());
        }
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("errors", errors);
        RequestDispatcher errorDispatcher = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/errors.jsp");
        try {
            errorDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException se) {
            System.out.println("Servlet Exception: " + se.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception: " + ioe.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI: You can just call `request.getRequestDispatcher()`. You don't need to chain through the session and servlet context objects (and you probably shouldn't anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It should work but I would test it this way:
 1. Do `<c:out value="${errors}"/>` to make sure that data exists in the request.
 2. Change name `error` to something else for example `err1` and display it to make sure there are no any name conflicts.
 3. Check that you added `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Answer (score -1):

Try to alert on each iteration, ideally it should be working.

Comment: I dont see a way to set an attribute in the response.

Comment: You can't set an attribute in response, I meant set it any other scope for testing purpose, like session etc, if it works it means your are not forwarding the request and your page have a new request object.